# Register a Background Task without running the app

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, background-task

**tl;dr**: How do I register a Background Task without having to run the app?

**Long version**:

I want to register a Background Task to run every time the user logs in using `SystemTriggerType.UserPresent` .

I've found information about registering the Task, but that is code that has to be executed. That would be fine if the Task only has to be executed *after* the app runs. But how do I register the Task *without* running the app?
A Background Task can be registered by

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
```

and then

```
builder.Name = taskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

As mentioned here: 
[Register a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/register-a-background-task) .

But as I said - my question is how to run this code before the app has ever been executed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `preInstalledConfigTask` extension in your manifest. This task will be started after your application is installed.

> Sometimes your application will need to update immediately after being
>   installed. This contract will enable you to immediately launch an
>   update task without any user interaction to make sure your application
>   is updated immediately.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx) is the full list of all the available extensions.

The `preInstalledConfigtask` can be set using the manifest editor:

[image: preinstall task in editor]

```
 <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.preInstalledConfigTask" EntryPoint="PreInstallTask.Task" />
  </Extensions>
```

You will find the extension definition in the [manifest schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn934791.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. +1. Though I'm not accepting yet until I can verify it. At the moment, though the Task (the UserPresent, not the preInstalled) seems to be registered, it's not called even when I log off and on again. (And I think it's supposed to be called even when I only lock the screen.)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question lately and what is missing in previous answers is that the Pre-Installed Configuration only triggers for OEMs & MOs. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/preinstall/preinstall-tasks).

That being said, it might be impossible to do what you want, as the task never triggers unless you are not managing the OS and shipping the image + having the necessary rights in your developer center. [See here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/preinstall/preinstallable-apps-for-windows-10-desktop)